# How to document all settings on a Windows 8.x machine

Tags: windows

I need to create a detailed document on all the hardware on a Windows 8.x x64 Enterprise machine, such as name and manufacturer of network adapters, driver version and date, etc. Is there a way to do this within Windows or with an additional software? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Win+R` and type `msinfo32.exe` to start System Information. From there you can export it using `File - Export` option.

Comment: Perfect! And it has an export tool. Thank you, @MustafaAKTAŞ.